# Boost.Log Expressions v1.71 will not compile under C++20

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

Including the `<boost/log/expressions.hpp>` header under C++20 (only tested under gcc 10.1), [causes a compilation failure](https://godbolt.org/z/ng6XnC):

```
/celibs/boost_1_71_0/boost/log/attributes/named_scope.hpp:128:29: error: 'reference' in 'boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attributes::named_scope_list::allocator_type' {aka 'class std::allocator<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attributes::named_scope_entry>'} does not name a type

  128 |     typedef allocator_type::reference reference;
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~
...
```

The code sample used is from [Boost's own examples](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/log/example/doc/sinks_sync.cpp).  Switching to C++17 or Boost v1.73 allows compilation to succeed.  Looking at the Boost.Log v1.73 changelog, there's this entry:

> Ported various components of the library to std::allocator_traits to
> improve compatibility with C++20 allocators.

The 'improve compatibility with' part implies that there's a way of making it work, does anyone know a workaround?  I'd rather not have to upgrade to v1.73.

Comment: Or, it implies that it is a work in progress. Please test with 1.73 and/or file a bug report. You're doing bleeding edge compilers, you will be expected to upgrade libraries for the necessary compatibility changes.

Comment: There is no workaround. If you want to use C++20, you have to either upgrade or patch 1.71 to use `std::allocator_traits`.